# XML error: Invalid document end at line 1, column 1

Tags: android, xml, web-services, joomla

-I activate the web service of joomla 
-I activate the xml-rpc joomla and XML-RPC - Blogger API, but the problem when I accede to the web service, it show me this page

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> 
<methodResponse> 
<fault> 
<value> 
<struct><member><name>faultCode</name> 
<value><int>105</int></value> 
</member> 
<member> 
<name>faultString</name> 
<value><string>XML error: Invalid document end at line 1, column 1</string></value> 
</member> 
</struct> 
</value> 
</fault> 
</methodResponse>
```

Any idea please?

Comment: what is the xml that you send?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand things - not greatly - the xmlrpc web service requires that you send (POST) xml to the service. If you just browse there you are in effect sending an empty GET request - and you will correctly receive this error.